# how to remove extreme values all columns by group in r

Tags: r, max, multiple-columns, min

Here is my dataframe:

```
ID  Dryweight   root    network number
1074    81.95   0.087877389 2.842105263 465
1074    57.11   0.08651187  1.7 367
1074    87.14   0.0840022   2.153846154 450
1074    75.52   0.085173817 2.068965517 532
1125    73.7    0.089987396 1.909090909 724
1125    75.41   0.089343593 1.628571429 516
1125    48.36   0.084626918 2.571428571 515
1125    66.33   0.078110279 1.567567568 503
1125    59.72   0.085949892 3   452
```

And what I want to do is to obtain a new dataframe after removing the max and min values of all columns by group(here should be based on ID). I tried to use "aggregate" but failed.

Comment: What do you mean when you want to remove the values? Do you want to drop the entire row? Do you want to set the value to missing? What is the desired output for this sample input. What did your `aggregate` attempt look like exactly?

Comment: Actually, I just want to delete 2 values( max and min values) for each column by ID, not to drop all the row.

Comment: Again, what does "delete" mean, set to NA? set to 0? What if there are ties?

Comment: For groups with only 2 members, you will get an empty data frame if you delete mins and maxs through all columns....is that what you expect?

Comment: no, just drop the max and min values.

Comment: sorry i did not notice there is a problem... and now I corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

Removing `min` or `max` per `id` *but will work only if each has the same number of hits for `min` and `max` and have some remaining*.

`split` it per `ID` and process the `list` with `lapply`. There go to each row using `apply` and subset by testing against `min` and `max`.

```
tt <- do.call(rbind, lapply(split(x, x[1])
  , function(y) cbind(ID=y[-1:-2,1], apply(y[-1], 2
     , function(z) z[z>min(z) & z<max(z)]))))
tt
#       ID Dryweight       root  network number
#[1,] 1074     81.95 0.08651187 2.153846    465
#[2,] 1074     75.52 0.08517382 2.068966    450
#[3,] 1125     73.70 0.08934359 1.909091    516
#[4,] 1125     66.33 0.08462692 1.628571    515
#[5,] 1125     59.72 0.08594989 2.571429    503
```

or setting `min` or `max` per `id` to `NA` which will work an any case.

```
cbind(x[1], do.call(rbind, lapply(split(x[-1], x[1])
  , function(y) apply(y, 2
     , function(z) z[c(NA, TRUE)[1 + (z>min(z) & z<max(z))]]))))
#    ID Dryweight       root  network number
#1 1074     81.95         NA       NA    465
#2 1074        NA 0.08651187       NA     NA
#3 1074        NA         NA 2.153846    450
#4 1074     75.52 0.08517382 2.068966     NA
#5 1125     73.70         NA 1.909091     NA
#6 1125        NA 0.08934359 1.628571    516
#7 1125        NA 0.08462692 2.571429    515
#8 1125     66.33         NA       NA    503
#9 1125     59.72 0.08594989       NA     NA
```

Data:

```
x <- structure(list(ID = c(1074L, 1074L, 1074L, 1074L, 1125L, 1125L, 
1125L, 1125L, 1125L), Dryweight = c(81.95, 57.11, 87.14, 75.52, 
73.7, 75.41, 48.36, 66.33, 59.72), root = c(0.087877389, 0.08651187, 
0.0840022, 0.085173817, 0.089987396, 0.089343593, 0.084626918, 
0.078110279, 0.085949892), network = c(2.842105263, 1.7, 2.153846154, 
2.068965517, 1.909090909, 1.628571429, 2.571428571, 1.567567568, 
3), number = c(465L, 367L, 450L, 532L, 724L, 516L, 515L, 503L, 
452L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Comment: Thank anyway, but what I want is a new dataframe without min and max, not to select or extract.

Comment: @wuqiannian You get a new `data.frame` without `min` and `max`.

Comment: Sorry I could not understand y[-1:-2,1] very well. What is the meanning of "-" or "-1:-2" here? And I guess the latter "1" refers to the first column probably.

Comment: @wuqiannian Have a look at: https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html#Index-vectors